# Inline styling of bootstrap-carousel active indicator

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the color of the active indicator for bootstrap-carousel. This is my code currently (without the active indicator styling)

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active" data-target="#DemoCarousel" style="background-color:#cccccc; border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px; border-color: transparent; height: 3px; width: 15px;">&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-target="#DemoCarousel" style="background-color:#cccccc; border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px; border-color: transparent; height: 3px; width: 15px;">&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-target="#DemoCarousel" style="background-color:#cccccc; border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px; border-color: transparent; height: 3px; width: 15px;">&nbsp;</li>
</ol>
```

Is there any way I can style the active indicator inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not because inline style overrides another style. if you want style active indicator then you can do something like this.

```
 li.active {
     background-color:red !important; 
 }
```

you need to use  `!important` here. it override your inline style.

But, if you want to style **active indicator**  using inline style. then you can look for a javascript solution.